# How to implement a 'social network' that is segregated based on email addresses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a basic social network for fun and would like to divide the site's content based on a user's email address. All functionality would be the same across the entire site, only the content would differ.

For example if a user signs up with a @berkeley.edu email address they can only friend, and comment, and view etc. other @berkeley.edu users. And users with @uoregon.edu email addresses can only friend, comment, and view, etc. other @uoregon.edu users.

What would be a good technique to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could multi-tenant the system keyed off of the email domain - then all queries would operate off of the that tenant key.

For example...

Tenant Table

> id, domain (1, 'berkeley.edu')
>
> id, domain (2, 'uoregon.edu')

User Table

> id, tenantId, email (1, 1, 'steve@berkeley.edu')
>
> id, tenantId, email (2, 1, 'fenton@berkeley.edu')
>
> id, tenantId, email (3, 2, 'steve@uoregon.edu')

Whenever you run a query, you include:

```
WHERE tenantId = 1
```

To only show users, content, messages, images etc from Berkeley.

Comment: Agreed, multi-tenancy is the way to go. If you want to subscribe, this RailsCast is probably what you need: http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes